# Random intercept and random slope for categorical variable in two level logit model

Tags: regression, logistic, mixed-model

I would like to ask you wheter is there a possibility to configure a random intercept and also a random slope in a multilevel binominal logit model.

Dependent variable is dichotomous (0/1), as for the IVs, there are more of them, but one of them is a nominal variable (categorical) I'd like to model this particural IV as a random slope.

Does it make sense to you? If so, is there a way to visualize the random slope in this case? (I do understand a random slope and a random intercept model in case of linear regression, but I find it rather difficult to understand it in context of logit regression).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where your difficulty lies.

If you understand this for a linear model, then understanding it for a logistic model depends on understanding the nature of logistic regression. Rather than being linear in the dependent variable itself (as in linear regression) it is linear in the logit. The random intercept and slope would be related to the logit, just as (in a linear model) they are related to the DV.

But you have a nominal IV. Random intercept still makes sense - it's sort of the base level of a person - but random slope becomes an odd terminology. You can have random effects of the IV, but I would hesitate to call it a slope since the IV has no order; in fact, "slope" sort of requires an interval or ratio level IV.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But just to be sure. Does it mean that every second level unit will have (possibly) different slope for the variable for which a random effect/slope has been modeled? It is not my main area of intrest, so it is still a bit confusing. Is there a possibility to provide any example of regression table or (if exist) an article?

Comment: Yes, that is what it means. But the reason for doing this is not because it is your area of interest but to a) Deal with violations of assumptions and b) Eliminate noise.